# How to use Event-Driven architecture to remove "api-based lambda calling another lambda" anti-pattern?

Tags: aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Suppose, I have an api `POST /order` which invokes `PlaceOrder` lambda and expects response from this. `PlaceOrder` lambda does some works, invokes another lambda `ProcessPayment` lambda and expects response. Also, `ProcessPayment` invokes `CreateInvoice` lambda expecting response. Whole architecture is like a `RequestResponse` cycle. I woulde like to achieve that *without lambda invoking another lambda* as it is considered as anti-pattern. My question is what is the best design pattern to achieve this behavior within *29 seconds* with *event-driven architecture*.

**What AWS suggests:** As per [this official](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/functions-calling-functions.html) documentation, they suggests to use SQS. But regarding using SQS, I have some thoughts.

**My thoughts:**

1. At event sources architecture, I can orchestrate these lambdas with SQS, SNS etc other event sources, but in that case, the nature would not be synchronous and thus I would not get response from the api.

**My other solution:**

1. Using Step Function: I can orchestrate this workflow with step function, and I think it is more elegant solution in this synchronous calling case. But I would like to achieve
   this via event sources.

How can I design this scenerio with best practices using event-based achitecture?

[image: Chaining]

Answer (score 1):

In an [Event-Driven Architecture](https://aws.amazon.com/event-driven-architecture/), the communication between producers and consumers is asynchronous by design, that's the way the architecture scales.

You can get nearly synchronous communication between 2 services in an EDA, by creating dedicated queues / channels to communicate between them, make sure they're scaled up to a level where the latency is acceptable (close to synchronous values).

This adds some complexity, because the services which need responses, have to wait in a hot-loop to get them as soon as possible, and also if messages are lost, you need to have retry policies, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to focus more on the mechanics of your program and a bit less on design patterns. You need to use the design patterns that fit your use-case, the other way around will not work. In the end, you build a program to fulfill a certain task or set of tasks, so that should be your end goal.

You’re stating that you have a process order Lambda, a create invoice Lambda and a process payment Lambda. I’d say the most interesting question is what you need to get done before you return a response to the user. Maybe you can process the order, respond to the user that it is done and handle the invoicing and payments on a later moment. Typically that would mean you put a message in a SQS queue or on an SNS topic.

It could be that you need your payment to be processed before you respond to the user, because they need to be informed about the status of the payment. You could then combine both actions in a single Lambda, because there is no way to spit the two tasks from one another. Keep in mind that often another option exist where you process the order first, put a message in a queue for the process payment (as it typically is a process that involves a third party) and the front end will poll for an update on the payment status. This way you can return a response quickly and still give an update on the payment as soon as possible.

The create invoice process is typically something you would never want to synchronously invoke during order confirmation. What if your invoicing application (intern or extern) is down? Theoretically you could still process orders as long as you create the invoice at some later moment in time. If you couple everything together you make order confirmation dependent on your invoice creation process, which I would regard as an unnecessary dependency.

I would really advice against step functions for this use-case. They can be utilized for long running processes that need to keep state and ‘wake up’ at specific moments, but for this specific flow I would say they do not help and are unnecessarily complex. If you have 3 things you need to do that you cannot separate from
one another, just run them in the same Lambda.

Comment: Hi @Bram, I have provided 3 lambdas just as an example, to raise up the problem. There are lots of lambdas in our system currently are calling each others synchronously. A calling B, B calling C, then D etc just like normal functions we are used to write in our programming lanaguages. I just want to get rid of this and introduce decoupled lambda functions which will use event-driven architecture. But, I am confused how to do this synchronously.

Comment: @Hasan _I am confused how to do this synchronously_ - that's the core of the issue - event driven architectures aren't meant to be synchronous. You can use AWS Step Functions with Express Workflows to orchestrate multiple lambda functions, but that's not an event driven architecture. It also doesn't make sense to insist on doing event driven architecture if it's not useful for your particular use case.